# Magento - Custom Payment Module

Tags: php, zend-framework, magento

This is a very general question, but here goes: I'm trying to create a custom payment module in Magento. I've created a 'regular' module that hooks into the Magento event/observer model. But how do I tell Magento to treat a module as a payment module, so it shows up in the admin backend AND on the checkout page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My general answer would be to try and reverse engineer the magento paypal module in magento core. Then you can create a module that will be similar to your desired functionality.

Also look at
http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/how-to/create-payment-method-module

and
http://activecodeline.net/writing-a-custom-module-in-magento-detailed-walktrough