# how do i install magento payment module created by me in magento site

Tags: magento, module, payment

recently i have customized a module that i installed from magento community. it is a payment module.i have modified it for my own payment gateway that  goes to a url and after payment completion,redirect user to magento site. it is working fine.but i want to make it as a module with that i can integrate my module with any magento site. i want to provide a option for install  or something like that.i don't know how to do that.

if anybody here.please help me.

Comment: [Writing a custom magento module](http://techportal.ibuildings.com/2010/04/20/writing-a-custom-magento-module/)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Magento - Custom Payment Module](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823355/magento-custom-payment-module)

Answer (score 0):

1. Package your extension (System -> Magento Connect -> Package Extensions)
2. Submit it to Magento Commerce (Login to magentocommerce.com and submit your packaged extension)